# Sign off from Merchant ship without Valid schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I am an indian seafarer onboard a merchant ship, My schengen visa has expired and my ship will be reaching brofjorden sweden, is it possible to get a transit visa and sign off the ship to travel to india

Comment: Do you have a Seaman’s Book? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44943/how-can-i-extend-my-schengen-seafarers-visa

Comment: What a great question !

Comment: This should be possible. From an internet search I even found companies that would help expedite the application and have someone escort you from dockside to the airport if you wished.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.